# ORA-0097 Group By Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got this select statement inside of a procedure:

```
SELECT activity_note, maint,hist_maint, position 
FROM   (SELECT activity_note, activity_count, maint, hist_maint, position
        FROM   (SELECT (CASE WHEN rfi IN (SELECT column_value 
                                          FROM   table(v_sum_pms_rfi_list))
                             THEN set_gid || '-PM-' || activity_note else set_gid || '-' || activity_note end) AS activity_note,
                       SUM(activity_count) AS ctivity_count
                FROM   dpt_production_activities
                WHERE  set_gid IN (1428, 1666)
                  AND  rfi IN (SELECT column_value FROM table(v_sum_pms_rfi_list))
                   OR  rfi in (SELECT column_value FROM table(v_sum_rfi_list))
                  AND  activity_code = 'COUNT'
                GROUP  BY activity_note, activity_count)
```

I'm getting the invalid group by error, ORA-0097. My understanding is that I need to have all selected columns in the group by, with the option of aggregated columns - so I'm feeding two variables (activity_note and activity_count) with the select statement - the former with a condition and the latter by an aggregated column

how do I put these into my group by? have I stumbled upon something that isn't viable or is there an elegant solution I just can't see

I should mention that the previous version of this worked fine, where the inner select statement didn't contain a case statement and the `GROUP BY` was `set_gid || '-' || activity_note`

Comment: I've edited your post significantly such that the syntax errors become obvious.  You're missing several closing parentheses for one thing.  Are you sure you included all of the query?  Also, you aliased one of your innermost select columns `ctivity_count` but then you grouped by `activity_count` instead.  (Unless that spelling mistake was introduced by a previous editor.)

Comment: What is the purpose of you `GROUP BY`? A `GROUP BY` is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns. I don't see any aggregate function (like `sum`,`count` etc.) used in your query. What aggregate function do you intend to use?

Comment: @dg99 someone edited the post and I accepted it, not realizing the errors and left my office before I had a chance to repaste the original query - you're right, activity_count was changed during that edit.

Comment: @Annjawn I'm trying to group by `activity_note` because `activity_count` is already aggregated and count is not and needs to be in the group by.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   SELECT activity_note, maint,hist_maint, position 
      FROM 
          (
           SELECT activity_note, SUM(activity_count) AS ctivity_count
                 FROM (
                       SELECT (CASE WHEN rfi IN 
                                   (
                                    SELECT column_value 
                                           FROM table(v_sum_pms_rfi_list)
                                    ) THEN    
                                     set_gid || '-PM-' || activity_note else set_gid || '-' || activity_note end) AS activity_note, activity_count
                       FROM dpt_production_activities)
                 WHERE set_gid in(1428, 1666)
                      AND rfi IN 
                              (SELECT column_value 
                                    FROM table(v_sum_pms_rfi_list)) 
                      OR rfi IN (SELECT column_value 
                                    FROM table(v_sum_rfi_list))
                      AND activity_code = 'COUNT'
                 GROUP BY activity_note))
```

Comment: tried that already. I've tried both variables and the entire case statement with and without the as

Comment: there are some syntax errors in what you have posted there, but, I'm guessing you just switched out the group by statement for the case statement without the AS? same error, ORA0097

Comment: @nbpeth YES may be i got that apologies for hit and try ... try now

Comment: same problem after correction, it's just a generic ora0097 error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49271/discussion-between-vikas-hardia-and-nbpeth)